# How to create an event receiver change permisions on file added sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, event-receiver

I have a library ("Documents") where I want to add an event receiver which will remove permisions on item added. I tryed already multiple ways to do this but i'm not so experimented and I can't figure where i'm wrong. With following code I managed to BreakInheritance, but didn't managed to remove all assignmets and add one new.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        if (properties.ListTitle.Equals("Documents"))
         I really need help on this one.{
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
            {
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPListItem li = properties.ListItem;
                            SPFile lf = web.GetFile(li.Url);

                            SPRoleType read = SPRoleType.Guest;
                            lf.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                            while (lf.Item.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
                            {
                                lf.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
                            }
                            AssignPermissionsToItem(lf.Item, user, read);
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
    {
        if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
        }

        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to instantiate new SPSite and SPWeb objects inside SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges ([link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/13/using-spsite-and-spweb-objects-with-runwithelevatedprivileges-don-t-cross-the-borders.aspx)).

Second, if you want to remove all rights, you should call [SPListItem.BreakRoleInheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms441135%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with false argument. In this case, item will have no rights. And then you can add whatever rights you need.

And my personal advice - you should never use empty catch-block. Send error message to UPS Logging service, it's really easy but helpful.

Comment: I solved myself the problem, I'll post tomorrow code if anyone is interested. Thanks anyway, your observation are true and I'll keep in mind the last one.